# Akka-HTTP template not found

Tags: java, scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I am using sbt to create an akka-HTTP project. The command I am using is "sbt new https://github.com/akka/akka-http-java-seed.g8."

But it says Template not found for: https://github.com/akka/akka-http-java-seed.g8.

What shall I do?

Comment: Just tried and it's working. Maybe you error is given by last dot you put in the end inside the double quotes. `sbt new https://github.com/akka/akka-http-java-seed.g8`

Comment: Even without the . dot it is saying the same

Answer (score 1):

You had a dot `.` after the url.

Comment: Even without the . dot it is saying the same

Answer (score 0):

The [Akka HTTP quickstart in Java](https://github.com/akka/akka-http-quickstart-java.g8) says that we should

- use Java 8 or higher
- SBT 0.13.13 or higher
- and the command is the following: `sbt -Dsbt.version=0.13.15 new akka/akka-http-java-seed.g8`

But I guess `sbt new akka/akka-http-java-seed.g8` will be enough.